# Are questions asking for deciphering texts on paintings (or other objects) allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic

[This question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/10924/whats-the-text-in-mystische-jagd-by-martin-schongauer), *What's the text in "Mystische Jagd" by Martin Schongauer?*, just got asked on Arts & Crafts SE.
The user presents us with a painting in which a Latin text in Gothic script is visible and asks for help reading it.
To be more generally applicable, I'll extend this question to all art objects.

Is this an appropriate question for History SE?

Comment: Not knowing Arts&Crafts:SE am a bit surprised: could you explain why this would be off-topic over there and compare it to why you think it would fit better here? (Very personally, IMO: it seems an acceptable fit for both…?) Such an explanation would seem especially useful if indeed "all art objects" should be handled in that way?

Comment: Our current description reads "*Arts & Crafts Stack Exchange is for artists and crafters, from professionals to hobbyists, who are interested in creating handmade, tangible works*". This question is not about creating, but about art appreciation, which is currently off-topic on A&C.

Comment: See also [What are all fantastic creatures on The Nile mosaic of Palestrina?](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/61722/47527) with 19 upvotes on History SE.

Comment: Okay, I moved it [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68372/whats-the-text-in-mystische-jagd-by-martin-schongauer). Thank you for your replies!